# REST API - filter choice field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field

How do you go about filtering the list using items from multi value field?
For example: If current user is the timekeeper for UnitA and UnitB, I want to filter another list to display only items from UnitA and UnitB.

Choice field name: UnitNames

I currently have the following to get the UnitNames:

```
var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Directory')/Items?$\
    filter=Title eq '" + currentUserEmail + "'&$\
    select=Id, UnitNames";

var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    async: false,  
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var countAjaxOrg = data.d.results.length;
            if(countAjaxOrg > 0) {
                var myUnitGroup = data.d.results[0].UnitNames;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) { alert("Failed to load data."); }
});
```

I tried a simple alert `alert(myUnitGroup);` and it returns `[object Object]`.  I need to filter another list with whatever values are returned from above but I cant figure out how to retrieve values from choice field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to add ".results" to the end of your call if you're using SP2013 or above:

```
var myUnitGroup = data.d.results[0].UnitNames.results;
```